# What is this center of the triangle called?

Tags: geometry

[image]

Construct three lines that pass through the centers of the excircles of triangle ABC and are perpendicular to the corresponding sides of the triangle. The three lines pass through the same red point.

I found this red point because I was inspired by the Nagle Point and the Mittenpunkt Point. I believe it has been discovered already, but I still have difficulty finding the name of the point. Hope people can provide the name of the point.

Comment: This could help http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TriangleCentroid.html

Comment: See if you can find it in Kimberling's [Encyclopedia of Triangle Centers](http://faculty.evansville.edu/ck6/encyclopedia/ETC.html).

Comment: FYI, the barycentric coordinates of this point are 

$$\begin{align}
\phantom{:}\sin A\;(\;1 + \cos A - \cos B - \cos C\;) \\ 
: \sin B\;(\;1 - \cos A + \cos B - \cos C\;) \\
: \sin C\;(\;1 - \cos A - \cos B + \cos C\;)
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks for the hint! But I still couldn't find it in the Encyclopedia. I tried to search it with command + F, but there weren't any same coordinates with the ones that you provided.

Comment: This appears to be $X(193)$ at the Encyclopedia of Triangle Centers, which is described only as "$X(9) - \text{Ceva Conjugate of}\; X(6)$". To find it, I calculated the trilinear coordinates (from my previous comment) based on a $6$-$9$-$13$ triangle, in accordance with [this table](http://faculty.evansville.edu/ck6/encyclopedia/Search_6_9_13.html).

Comment: Ok, now I think I have found it.

Comment: @Blue: Do you mean "X(4)-CEVA CONJUGATE OF X(2)"? I think X(9)−Ceva Conjugate of X(6) is for X(198).

Comment: Whoops. I got the title correct, but $X$-number wrong. (Weird.) I meant $X(198)$. You can see that the "trilinears" for $X(198)$ almost match my previous comment, except for an $a$ where I have $\sin A$, and for multiplication by $-1$.  Trilinears are essentially proportions, so the $-1$ is an immediate non-issue. Likewise, proportionality allows us to trade the $a$ factor for $\sin A$, because, by the Law of Sines, $a/\sin A=b/\sin B=c/\sin C$.

Answer (score 0):

This is a really famous triangle center. It's called [Bevan point](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BevanPoint.html). It is also the circumcenter of the excentral triangle of the reference triangle. Kimberling center [$X_{40}$](https://faculty.evansville.edu/ck6/encyclopedia/ETC.html#X40).